# Why does my websocket close after a few minutes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm using ws with node.js on the server side and the regular WebSocket API on the client side.  Opening the connection and messaging a few times back and forth works fine.  But the socket always closes after a minute or two.  Aren't they supposed to persist?  Am I doing something wrong?

My server is node.js hosted on heroku.  I just tested locally again using `foreman start` (the heroku tool to run the server locally) and the socket doesn't close unexpectedly at all, so perhaps it's a misconfiguration on heroku.  Anyway, here's a relevant code sample with a few functions omitted for brevity.

I'm testing the application in Chrome on OSX Yosemite but have seen the same behavior in Chrome on Windows 7 when running against production environment.

server:

```
// Client <-> Host Protocol functions.  Move to a different file so that they can be shared.
var C2H_SIGNAL_TYPE_REGISTER = "register";

var H2C_SIGNAL_WELCOME = "welcome";
var H2C_SIGNAL_TYPE_ERROR = "error";
var H2C_SIGNAL_TYPE_PEER_ADDED = "peer_joined";
var H2C_SIGNAL_TYPE_PEER_LEFT = "peer_left";

// Update channel endpoint names.
var UPDATE_ENDPOINT_PEERS = "/peers";

// Create a signal message with all asociated default properties.
// Signal senders should create this object and update it accordingly when
// building a signal message to send to a peer.
function createHostMsg(type)
{
    var msg = { signalType: type };

    if ( type == H2C_SIGNAL_WELCOME ) {
        // Since we're sending a welcome message, we need to provide a list
        // of currently connected clients.
        msg.peers = {};
        for ( var addr in clients ) {
            console.log("addr " + addr);
            var c = clients[addr].description;
            if ( c && c.id ) {
                msg.peers[c.id] = c;
            }
        }
    }

    return msg;
}

// require modules. 
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');

// Tracks connected peers.
var clients = { };

// 1.  Configure the application context settings.
var app = express();
app.enable('trust proxy');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(multer()); // for parsing multipart/form-data

// a. configure http routers.  these will handle requests coming from app.
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.get('/app', peerApp);
app.get('/script/:name', publicScriptRouter);

// 2.  Create the http server itself, passing app to be the request handler.
// app will handle routing and multiplexing of incoming requests to different
// route middleware handlers.
var http = require('http');
var WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen( app.get('port') );

// 3.  Create one of these for all socket endpoints.
var wss = new WebSocketServer( { server: httpServer, path: UPDATE_ENDPOINT_PEERS } );

wss.on("connection", function(webSocket) {

    // 1.  Associate the socket with the remote address it came from.
    var remoteAddress = webSocket._socket.remoteAddress;
    var remotePort = webSocket._socket.remotePort;
    var clientConnID = remoteAddress + ":" + remotePort;

    var exists = clients[clientConnID] != null;
    if ( exists ) {
        console.log("socket server connection: associating new connection from %s with registered peer.", clientConnID);
        clients[clientConnID].socket = webSocket;
    } else {
        console.log("socket server connection: associating new connection from %s with unregistered peer.", clientConnID);
        clients[clientConnID] = { description: null, socket: webSocket };
    }   

    // 2.  Hook up handlers for communication over this particular socket.
    webSocket.on("message", function(data, flags) {
        processMessage(webSocket, data, flags);
    });

    webSocket.on("close", function() {
        // Praise satin for closures!!
        removePeer(clientConnID);
    });

});

// Transduce the message and handle it accordingly.
function processMessage(socket, data, flags)
{
    var msg = JSON.parse(data);
    if ( !msg.signalType ) {

        var msg = createHostMsg( H2C_SIGNAL_TYPE_ERROR );
        msg.errStr = "message_malformed";
        socket.send( JSON.stringify( msg ) );

    } else if ( msg.signalType == C2H_SIGNAL_TYPE_REGISTER ) {
        handleRegistration(socket, msg);
    }
}
```

client:

```
function initSignalChannel()
{
    rtcPeer.channel = new WebSocket( location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws') + "/peers" );
    rtcPeer.channel.onmessage = updateChannelMessage;
    rtcPeer.channel.onopen = function(event) { 
        console.log("remote socket opened");
    }
    rtcPeer.channel.onclose = function(event) {
        console.log("host closed remote socket.");
    }
}

function updateChannelMessage(event) {

    var msgObj = JSON.parse(event.data);

    if ( !msgObj || !msgObj.signalType ) {

        console.log("updateChannelMessage: malformed response!! %o", msgObj );

    } else if ( msgObj.signalType == "welcome" ) {

        console.log("updateChannelMessage: received welcome from host.");
        handleWelcome(msgObj);

    } else if ( msgObj.signalType == "peer_joined" ) {
        console.log("updateChannelMessage: received peer_joined from host.");
        if ( msgObj.peer.id == rtcPeer.description.id ) {
            console.log("updateChannelMessage: peer_joined: received notification that I've been added to the room. " + msgObj.peer.id);
            console.log(msgObj);
        } else {
            console.log("updateChannelMessage: peer_joined: peer %s is now online.", msgObj.peer.id);
            console.log(msgObj);
            addRemotePeer( msgObj.peer );
        }
    }

}

function addRemotePeer(peerObj)
{
    remotePeers[peerObj.id] = peerObj;
    var ui = createPeerUIObj(peerObj);
    $("#connectedPeerList").append( ui );
}

function createPeerUIObj(peerObj)
{
    var ui = null;
    if ( peerObj ) {
        ui = $("<li></li>");
        var a = $("<a></a>");

        a.append("peer " + peerObj.id);
        ui.append(a);
        ui.click(function(event) { console.log("clicked");});
    }

    return ui;
}

function handleWelcome(msgObj)
{
    if ( msgObj.id ) {

        console.log("updateChannelMessage: welcome: received id from host. " + msgObj.id);
        console.log(msgObj);
        rtcPeer.description.id = msgObj.id;

        for ( var p in msgObj.peers ) {
            addRemotePeer(msgObj.peers[p]);
        }

    } else {
        console.log("updateChannelMessage: malformed response.  no id.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your node.js code and your client code, we cannot help you without it

Comment: It's also worth describing what your infrastructure is for the server (hosting facility, proxies, etc...) because some do not allow long running, inactive sockets.

Comment: Looks like you have a firewall or a anti-virus filter proxy installed which doesn't support websockets. But as Marco and jfriend00 already said knowing your code and your environment whould be useful.

Comment: Thanks all.  Putting together a proper description and will get back to you with it shortly.  Appreciate it.

Comment: Is the connection idle for those few minutes?  Idle tcp connections often get closed by one end or the other.

Comment: Yes it is idle.  But the connection never closes if I'm running the server locally.  It only closes on heroku backend.

Comment: Regarding @jfriend00 comment, I believe that heroku does proxy the application because it assigns every application a random subdomain of herokuapp.com, e.g. some-app-3213.herokuapp.com/path/to/resource.

Comment: I didn't realize that it was a heroku dependent problem, but I just did some googling for their forums and found the following.  After the initial response, each byte sent (either from the client or from your app process) resets a rolling 55 second window. If no data is sent during this 55 second window then the connection is terminated and a H15 error is logged.   https://discussion.heroku.com/t/websocket-closes-after-60-seconds/333

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for the comments everyone.  It turns out that jfriend00 had the right answer, I just didn't realize that the hosting service I was using wouldn't allow for the connection to be kept open.

From the below forum posting, the solution is

> you'll need to make your clients ping the server periodically to keep the socket alive.

Not the most ideal situation, but indeed doable.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.